# Activity's Up button to navigate to different activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-toolbar, android-navigation, up-button

I have an activity `MyActivity` with the standard Up button implemented in its toolbar (left arrow on top-left of screen).

**This activity is unique in that the user can navigate to it from multiple activities in my app.**

I need this Up button to direct to the activity that the user came from (same behavior as Android Back button).

Instead, it always directs back to the Home activity, even if the user did not immediately come from there, because of this code in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.myapp.activity.MyActivity"
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.myapp.activity.Home"
/>
```

How do I override this behavior so that `MyActivity`'s Up button returns the user to the activity that he came from and not always the Home activity?

Comment: why have you declared it as a parent activity?

Comment: just remove meta-data declaring parent activity if you don't want to go to home activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, replace your code with this.**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

**Second, add a few codes to your "MyActivity" class.**
1. at onCreate() method, add that line.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnable(true);
```

2. implement onOptionItemSelected(), add a few lines.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                     super.onBackPressed();
                }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Hope it works!

Comment: 1) Remove the empty intent filter. 2) Use `getSupportActionBar()` if you're using appcompat. 3) You probably meant `this.onBackPressed` instead of `super.onBackPressed`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove meta-data declaring parent activity if you don't want to go to home activity.

```
<activity android:name="com.myapp.activity.MyActivity" />
```

or you can use toolbar's onNavigationClick to define your own action on back press:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //if you want to go one activity back then put onBackPressed() method
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't mix Toolbar and ActionBar. If the up button worked because of an entry in the manifest, it means a toolbar has been set as Action bar manually or there is the default Action bar present. Use the Action bar API.

Answer (score -1):

Replace with this:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: This code remove the Up button entirely from this activity's toolbar. I need to keep the up button, but have it navigate back to last activity user was on.

Comment: You have to use custom toolbar for this